# MCP23017 Is it possible to get INTCAPB captured output pins state at the moment of INTA input pins state exception happen?

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I want to interface 8x8 keypad matrix with raspberry pi using MCP23017 i2c extender. I'm able to do this with both ways described:

- Simple loop by setting GPIOA to input and GPIOB to output first, then looping through 1 to 8 setting GPIOB bit to output and then comparing GPIOA inputs for state change at delay
- Setting GPIOB to output first and pulling them all high, then setting GPIOA to input and interrupt for INTA, in interrupt - repeat loop described previously.

The problem with both those ways is I want to reduce cpu usage, and would love to make it this way:

Set GPIOB to output, GPIOA to input, set INTA interrupt on GPIOA change, in main loop with delay set GPIOB to row from 1 to 8, and on interrupt happens - get GPIOA `AND` GPIOB `at the moment of interrupt` with INTCAPA and INTCAPB, and thus no need for checking loops, just get button from `keypad[intcapa_row][intcapb_col]` - and thats it.

But I'm struggling getting INTCAPB with that scenario, at the moment of INTA interrupt INTCAPB always 0x00 no matter what. I could use GPIOB instead, but main loop can change it between next loop and interrupt happened in another thread - and I get wobbly results.

So, does anyone know, is it possible to get second port values when first port fires interrupt at exactly this moment? Thx.

Comment: You only need to sample the keypad maybe at 100 Hz, so the CPU usage should be negligible… You must be sampling it way too fast perhaps?

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica no I sampled with delay every row for 2ms - so in total I guess its ~20ms per keypad total, and I would not say its negligible. But I make it on bit-bashing "soft" i2c line though.